# Internet Explorer 10 - Text renders just below centre

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have a weird rendering issue on IE 10, When I load up a page of information, all of the textboxes text render just off centre to the bottom.

[image: preview of what should be the number 3]

*Not sure why the picture isn't rendering.... hope you get enough of the problem though!*

This only happens when information is loaded to the browser, and only happens in IE, Firefox and Chrome seem to be fine.

Is it OK when I type in a textbox.

Here is an example of a textbox line of code in my view

```
 <td>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.property)
 </td>
```

I have tried to do the following to help on page ready

```
$('.txtBox').each(function () {
    // trys to Helps render properly in IE
    $(this).css("line-height", "4px")
});
```

But to no prevail

Is there anything I could do with the HTML or maybe in the CSS?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any styles set on the input? If so please provide these as well. based on your picture it looks like it could be a `line-height` or `height`issue. Have you tried changing these styles?

Comment: Can you see the picture then? on Chrome and IE, it display broken for me... a related issue maybe? However, I have tried to put line-height on these textboxes but it never worked. so no, this is just how it renders without any CSS

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the issue,

its because I have a line-height on the table

```
<table style="line-height:30px;">
```

Therefore it wasnt just pushing down the Rows, but obviously the text